# Correct way in Flex to make a transparent panel respond to rollOver() events

Tags: apache-flex, rollover

I have a Canvas in a Flex application which has items inside it that cover only about 50% of the area of the main canvas.

i want the canvas to respond to `rollOver` events for the full area, and not just the area that is covered by the items inside.

I have been setting the following attributes to achieve this :

```
<mx:Canvas backgroundColor="white"
backgroundAlpha=".01"
rollOver="rollOver(event)">...
```

This causes the entire canvas to respond to rollOver events. It works great - I'm just not happy with it and figure there must be a better way to achieve it.

Is there a way to force mouse events to act on the entire area of a UIComponent?

Comment: What do you mean you're 'not happy' with it even though 'it works great'. What other functionality are you looking for? Does it flicker or something, or is it turning off when you rollover a child of the canvas and you want to prevent that?

Comment: it just seems like there ought to be something especially designed for it. also there is unnecessary graphically intensive work going on because it is having to render that background - which it has to do even thought you cant actually see it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing is perfectly acceptable, although using the arbitrary alpha value of 0.01 is unnecessary, you can set it's backgroundAlpha to a simple 0.

I routinely use Canvases for complicated multi layered UI's and set up my default Canvas style via css to have a backgroundAlpha of 0 and a backgroundColor of #ffffff, then, if I need a canvas to actually be visible I adjust it's individual backgroundAlpha and backgroundColor properties.

There's nothing wrong with setting a graphic object's alpha to 0 so that it still responds to events but hasn't been 'turned off' entirely, us AS coders do it all the time!

Comment: i never tried 0. it was probably the 0.01 more than anythin that made me skeptical of what i was doing

Answer (score 0):

What about ignoring transparency sections of an image? In my case I would like the roll over effect to occur only if the visible section of an image is rolled over, not the transparent part. Is this possible?

Comment: if you have an image with transparency i think it will do this automaticallyh for you. i've done this before with PNG files compressed as swf files i thought.

Answer (score -2):

You could do this:

```
import flash.event.MouseEvent;
...
canvas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,function(event:MouseEvent):void {
    ...
});
```

where "canvas" is the ID of the canvas in your mxml.

Comment: this is equivalent to what i originally had in my MXML