# Why do DragOver/Enter events require a background on Canvas?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a canvas which I want to accept drags on.

I have added a dragOver and dragEnter event listeners to the canvas, but they only work if I drag over something inside the canvas (another child element).

I realised that if I set the canvas' background colour to black it works. So I have set it's background transparency to 0, which works... buy is there a better way to work around this apparent need for the canvas to have something inside it to accept dragEvents.

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to one of the Flex developers, "In Flash there is a difference between a transparent pixel and an area in a Sprite that hasn't been drawn on at all." (http://www.mail-archive.com/flexcoders@yahoogroups.com/msg127690.html)

I'm guessing this is the reason why you need to have the transparent background.  For what it's worth, this is always the way I've seen this problem solved.  There is also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291927/correct-way-in-flex-to-make-a-transparent-panel-respond-to-rollover-events) which talks about this problem.

Hope this helps!